# Modal.Header closeButton event registration

Tags: reactjs

**Note**

**This is not about the custom button placed inside the footer. It is about the closeButton placed inside modal header tag.**

I am using Modal in React.js and following this article: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

It seems like there is no way to register click event for closeButton in header according to the documentation.

Can you suggest something?

**Code**

```
<Modal.Dialog>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>

    <Modal.Body>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
    </Modal.Body>

    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="primary">Save changes</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal.Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs:
[image]

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#api

[image]

This way the `handleClose` will set the `show` flag.
Other than that `handleClose` can include any other logic too.

**UPDATE**

`closeButton` in `Modal.Header` is just a boolean prop.

You can check the source at [Github](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/ModalHeader.tsx).

`closeButton: PropTypes.bool,` [Line](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/9645a51f8a71ec60869a85ac41d2f7e76c0bfe9d/src/ModalHeader.tsx#L36)

```
const defaultProps = {
  closeLabel: 'Close',
  closeButton: false,
};
```

Going one level deeper `ModalHeader` actually uses `AbstractModalHeader` [Line](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/9645a51f8a71ec60869a85ac41d2f7e76c0bfe9d/src/ModalHeader.tsx#L55)

[image]